# Remover espaço e quebra de linhas em string

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Estou fazendo um WebAPI que gera um XML, esse XML é lido diversas vezes ao dia, então na primeira execução ele serializa todo o meu XML e salva em disco, e durante 24h ele lê do disco ao invés de serializar todo o objeto novamente.

Faço isso pois tem vários acessos, os XML são grandes alguns com até 300mb, e as informações podem ser cacheadas por 24h

O Problema é que o campo descrição, creio que ele poderia ser 'compactado' ou melhor poderia tentar fazer um minify no xml antes de gravar ele em disco. estou tentando remover os espaços em brancos e quebras de linhas só desse campo por enquanto assim já reduzo alguns bons megas.

Utilizo Webapi em C#, Redis, MSSQL

Hoje estou enviando ela assim:

```
    <description><![CDATA[SOBRADO

Área Terreno: 8 x 28
Área Construída: 170m&sup2;

Pavimento Superior:
2 dormitórios sendo 1 dormitorio com armario embutido planejado e um maste
banheiro
jardim de inverno
sacada


Pavimento Térreo:
2 salas
Copa
Cozinha
Corredor lateral
jardim na frente
quintal

Edícula:
1 dormitórios
banheiro
lavanderia
deposito

4 vagas

IPTU R$ 1.200,00 anual]]></description>
```

**Gostaria de enviar assim:**

```
<description><![CDATA[SOBRADO Área Terreno: 8 x 28    Área Construída: 170m&sup2;...
```

Utilizo 2 funções para tentar limpar o código, mas ainda não está como gostaria.

```
description = Biblioteca.RemoveTroublesomeCharacters(Biblioteca.CorrigeDescricao(imovel.Descricao)),

internal static string CorrigeDescricao(string descricao)
{
    var tab = '\u0009';
    descricao = descricao.Replace("  ", " ");
    descricao = descricao.Replace("=\r\n", "");
    descricao = descricao.Replace(";\r\n", "");
    descricao = descricao.Replace("\t", " ");
    descricao = descricao.Replace(tab.ToString(), "");
    return RemoveHtml(descricao);
}
```

E

```
 internal static string RemoveTroublesomeCharacters(string inString)
        {
            if (inString == null) return null;

            var newString = new StringBuilder();
            char ch;

            for (int i = 0; i < inString.Length; i++)
            {
                ch = inString[i];
                // remove any characters outside the valid UTF-8 range as well as all control characters
                // except tabs and new lines
                //if ((ch < 0x00FD && ch > 0x001F) || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
                //if using .NET version prior to 4, use above logic
                if (XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(ch)) //this method is new in .NET 4
                {
                    newString.Append(ch);
                }
            }
            return newString.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: E qual é seu problema?

Comment: quero remover espaços em brancos, quebras de linha tentar minificar o arquivo, alguns tem 300mb se eu conseguir remover alguns caracteres já pode significar uns 20mb no final

Comment: @Dorathoto, que tipo de aplicação vai consumir o seu serviço? todas são .NET?

Comment: não, a maioria creio que seja em java..mas não sei as tecnologias deles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dorathoto, acredito que melhor que remover os espaços da string, seja compactar todo o Response.

A maneira mais facil de se faze-lo sem configura-lo direto no IIS, é instalando o seguinte NuGet: [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Compression](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server/)

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server
```

Então execute a seguinte configuração no StartUp da sua WebAPI.:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, 
    new ServerCompressionHandler(
        new GZipCompressor(), 
        new DeflateCompressor()));
```

[Resposta Original (EN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815706/webapi-gzip-when-returning-httpresponsemessage#answer-29014637)

Comment: Parece interessante, no meu primeiro teste, percebi que parece impactar bastante na perfomance o que é algo bem delicado no meu caso, tive até que aplicar o Redis para tentar acelerar o processo que já não era leve.

Comment: @Dorathoto, como disse esta é uma forma de aplicar a compactação direto no codigo, uma outra forma seria ativar ela direto no IIS, procure por `WebAPI GZip on IIS`, tente faze-lo e compatilhe o resultado conosco.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode resolver a questão dos excessos de ***quebra de linha*** e ***espaço*** com REGEX :

#### Removendo excessos

```
pattern : (\s){2,}
replace : $1
```

> Vai capturar *carateres de espaçamento* que se repitam mais de duas vezes e substituir por um so. Note que ele substitui pelo primeiro encontrado.

#### Exemplo

```
'teste de quebra    '
'de linha     '
```

Aplicando ficaria assim:

```
'teste de quebra de linha '
```

pois ela uniu o `'     \n'` e substituiu por `' '`, pois `' '` foi o primerio encontrado

#### Removendo quebras de linha

```
pattern : (\n){2,}
replace : $1
```

> São similares, mas não igual pois esta considera apenas quebra de linha, talvez seja necessario alterar para (\n\r?){2,} pois Windows algumas IDEs de windows ainda acrescentam o *retorno de carro*.

#### Exemplo

```
'quebra de linha     '

'em duas     '
```

Aplicando fica assim:

```
'quebra de linha'
'em duas'
```

Comment: bem interessante...

Comment: como faria isso em C# ? descricao = Regex.Replace(descricao, @"(\n){ 2,}");

Comment: @Dorathoto `Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern); String result = rgx.Replace(descricao, replacement);`

Answer (score 2):

**NUNCA** trate XML como texto. Existem termos para quem faz isso que, embora sejam termos técnicos e inclusive utilizados em livros, fariam com que eu fosse banido daqui se os utilizasse ;)

Ao invés disso, encapsule tudo o que você quer ter no XML como um objeto que seja serializável. Em seguida, utilize as classes de XML do Framework para gerar o XML quando for gravar, ou ler a partir de um arquivo. Isso não só manterá o XML compacto, como garantirá boa formatação e lhe economizará horas de desenvolvimento.

Comece por esta classe: [XmlWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: nem tinha reparado que ele estava a montar o `XML` na mão, pensei que ele queria apenas remover os caracteres da `Descricao`, em todo caso ele não deveria implementar nada neste sentido, afinal a `WebAPI` vai retornar um `JSON` ou `XML` depedendo do header `Accept` enviado pelo cliente.

Comment: não trato como texto, faço toda uma serialização do meu xml.

Comment: @Dorathoto, o que estamos tentando dizer, é que o metodo `RemoveTroublesomeCharacters` parece ser desnecessário, o JSON.NET deveria ser capaz de lidar com isto sem a necessidade de qual quer intervenção. Então você precisaria apenas definir um modelo, popular o mesmo, e retornar ele, a WebAPI já iria serializar o modelo como XML caso o cliente informe que deseja um XML pelo Header Accept.

Comment: RemoveTroublesomeCharacters  uso pra garantir apenas encoding utf-8 Acho que não fui claro na pergunta, faço o modo correto, serializo perfeitamente como deve ser com o webapi, é que alem disso eu acabo também gravando o xml fisicamente e esses arquivos tem se tornado grandes

Comment: fiz uma edição na pergunta, não estava clara o suficiente

Answer (score -1):

Estava com um problema parecido porém eu precisava que a descrição ficasse com no máximo uma quebra de linha e no máximo um espaço entre palavras, incluindo tabs.
Segue abaixo o uso do pattern que pode resolver seu problema:

[image: Texto de exemplo]

Usando o pattern com regex replace
[image: Regex usada usando Ignore Case em C#]

[image: Resultado da descricao com a regex aplicada]